# multiple regex matches on one line not working

Tags: python, regex

I have some HTML which I want to extract out text blocks that:

- begin with either `#` or `|` (pipe symbol)
- followed by some text and a 'ticker' in brackets
- followed by all text until the next match

Sample code:

```
text = """
#Test name 1 (ABCD) blah blah# some more text 1||Test name 2 (EFGH) blah blah some more text 2
#Test name 3 (IJKL) blah blah#  some more text 3
|Test name 4 (MNOP) blah blah||some more text 4
|Test name 5 (QRST) blah blah||some more text 5|
"""
expr = r'(?P<alltext>(#|\|)[^<>]+\((?P<ticker>[A-Z]{1,10})\)(?P<bodytext>.*))'
compiled_expr = re.compile( expr, re.MULTILINE)
matches = re.finditer(expr,text)
for match in matches:
    d=match.groupdict()
    print d['alltext']
```

Sample output

```
#Test name 1 (ABCD) blah blah# some more text 1||Test name 2 (EFGH) blah blah some more text 2
#Test name 3 (IJKL) blah blah#  some more text 3
|Test name 4 (MNOP) blah blah||some more text 4
|Test name 5 (QRST) blah blah||some more text 5|
```

This doesn't pick up the two matches on the first line. What I need is for it to detect 'Test name 2...'

So the output I want would be:

```
#Test name 1 (ABCD) blah blah# some more text 1|
|Test name 2 (EFGH) blah blah some more text 2
#Test name 3 (IJKL) blah blah#  some more text 3
|Test name 4 (MNOP) blah blah||some more text 4
|Test name 5 (QRST) blah blah||some more text 5|
```

Comment: According to your criteria, why `# some more text 1` is not a separate match?

Comment: @thefourtheye: That's because there are no braces `()` in `# some more text 1`.

Comment: You don't need the multi-line modifier. And this `[^<>]+` greedily matches every character in your string (everything) because you don't have those characters. As a result, from the first # to  the last set of parenthesis are matched, then the parenthesis, then the rest.

Comment: @Zio I have merged the new question into this one. Please *do not* post duplicates like this again. You should not have done a "fundamental" edit here in the first place, but posting a duplicate isn't the way to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[#|][^#|]*?\(.*?\).*?(?=(?:[#|][^#|]*?\(.*?\))|$)`, with single-line modifier (aka "dot matches all").

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/tY4jI1/1)

Explanation:

```
[#|] # match "#" or "|"
[^#|]*? # any text except "#" or "|", up until the next...
\( #..."("
.*? # any text enclosed in the braces
\) # and a closing brace
.*? # finally, any text until the next match OR the end of the string.
(?=
    (?: # this is the same pattern as before.
        [#|]
        [^#|]*?
        \(
        .*?
        \)
     )
|
    $
)
```

Comment: 'Single line modifier' do you mean dot matches all? This `.*?` at the end of your lookahead is not really needed.

Comment: Yes, dot matches all is what I mean. And you're right about the `.*?`too. I'll remove it.

Comment: Just to mention, by default regex are 'single line' with respect to anchors `^$` meaning BOS/EOS, as opposed to 'multi-line' where they additionally mean BOL/EOL. The confusion people have is legacy  documentation incorrectly specifies the `s` modifier as `single line` where it has no effect on anchors `^$` at all. Probably %50 of the time in regex, `sm` are used simultaneously, but the result is not 'single-multiline mode'. Its better form to say `Dot-All` or dot matches newline too, because it's precise and avoids confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @sln. I called it "single-line" because that's how regex101.com labels it, but I'll take care not to call it that in the future.